# Rails sanitizing user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For user inputed data I am taking the approach of sanitizing it before saving to strip out any html or anything malicious (i.e.  tags).

I have a `before_validation` callback:

```
before_validation    :sanitize_fields

def sanitize_fields
  full_sanitizer = Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new
  white_list = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new

  # Only text allowed
  self.fname = full_sanitizer.sanitize(self.fname)
  self.lname = full_sanitizer.sanitize(self.lname)
  self.company = full_sanitizer.sanitize(self.company)

  # Some HTML Allowed
  self.description = white_list.sanitize(self.description)
end
```

The problem I am encountering is that when saving something like "Smith & Company" as the name it is stored in the DB as `Smith &amp; Company`.  Not an issue per se, but then it also displays as `Smith &amp; Company` in the edit view of the form, which seems funny and confusing to the end user.

Is there a better way than the approach I am taking?  This "smells" wrong to me.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be so worried about stripping out tags. If a user enters `<sarcasm>sure</sarcasm>` into a field, they expect to see the tags rendered as text

Comment: I been working on smth like this, and ended up with MarkDown. Much cooler and cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are confident the data is sanitized, you can declare it [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) in the views to avoid it showing up as `&amp;`; it will render exactly as provided.

This of course begs the question: rather than jump through hoops to pre-sanitize and then tell the view that it has been sanitized, why not just allow the view to sanitize strings like it does by default? If you render the string `"<tag>some_stuff</tag>"` in a view, it will escape it for you. Are you concerned about the unsanitized string appearing elsewhere other than in a view that you control?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I agree I should remove my pre-sanitization.  But then how would I render `<tag>some &amp; stuff</tag>` as `<tag>some & stuff</tag>`.  I have instances where the `&` is stored as `&amp;`.

Comment: Could I wrap it in `CGI.unescapeHTML`?

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest, you beat me to it. Would it be impractical to run a backfill script offline to unescape the existing data and save it back to the db? That would be my preferred approach, then you don't have to worry about figuring out if it was sanitized or not. Otherwise you have to keep messy `if` statements all over to switch if you actually want to unescape or not.

Comment: They are coming in on a regular basis via an API.  I'd hate to add those `CGI.unescapeHTML` all over my app - probably the best approach would be for me to catch it at the point of insertion from the api and run a `.gsub` to look for it....or perhaps on a `:before_save` callback at the model

Comment: One bridge approach could be to create a duplicate but initially unused column to store the unescaped data. `after_save` you can populate those fields with the correct data. You can then run the backfill to catch up previous data that is not actively being saved. In the meantime, new data will have the correct data also stored in the new but unused column. Once the backfill is done, you can flip the switch by dropping the old column and renaming the new column to the old. (Or renaming both, so that the operation is reversible in case anything is screwed up)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it smells wrong is because it is.

With the possible exception of pe-rendering large text (markdown, etc) blocks into html, I would avoid sanitizing your model data this way. Following rails best practices will protect you from SQL injection, text output in views will be rendered in a safe way by default.

If you need to allow users to input html, sanitize it on output (in your view) not on input.

Separation of concerns is one reason, but the biggest is that what you are trying to do is simply not idiomatic rails. If you chose to continue down that path you will be fighting the framework constantly.